# Bath tub stopper won't go down into "locked" position anymore

Tags: drain, bathtub

I took off the bathtub stopper and now, when I put it back down into the drain, it won't push down into the locked position! Gahhh....

Basically, the stopper will fit into the drain, but it's left perpetually in the "open" position. I've tried multiple orientations, and I'm pretty sure I've got the right orientation, but it just won't pop down like it used to...Any ideas? It's a Grohe tub, if that helps.

Image: the circle on the right is the bottom of the stopper, the circle on the left is the drain that it fits down onto. [image]

Comment: When you push down, does anything move at all (just not far enough), or is it all frozen?  Hard to tell, but does this have threads?  Can you spin the stopper after you put it in position?

Comment: Good question! It doesn't move at all when I push down. It does have threads on the rubber, outer edge of the stopper, yes. I can spin the stopper if I put it in one position, but not all positions where it could fit.